# Setting per-application volume in JACK

Tags: linux, audio, jack, audio-volume

Is it possible to set the volume on a per-application basis in JACK as in pulseaudio? I know that `pavucontrol` can do that for PA but is it possible to do the same for JACK via something like `QJackCtl`?

I couldn't find anything about that both via searching through internet and through `Cadence` and `qjackctl`.

Although the volume can be changed within all professional audio production softwares(i.e the JACK use case),but I cannot do that with the global shortcuts,so for example I have to use the mouse or use the application-specific shortcuts.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cadence and QjackCtl do not have any volume controls

per-application volume controls would require an additional mixer package like
[jack_mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6DpO.jpg)